# How to replace Perl-style regex with MatchData object

Tags: ruby, regex, rubocop

I am using the `gsub` method with a regular expression:

```
@text.gsub(/(-\n)(\S+)\s/) { "#{$2}\n" }
```

Example of input data:

```
"The wolverine is now es-
sentially absent from 
the southern end
of its European range."
```

should return:

```
"The wolverine is now essentially
absent from  
the southern end
of its European range."
```

The method works fine, but rubocop reports and offense:

> Avoid the use of Perl-style backrefs.

Any ideas how to rewrite it using `MatchData` object instead of `$2`?

Comment: One might use named captures (and refer them as `\k<>`) as well: `.gsub(/-\n(?<rest>\S+)\s/, "\\k<rest>\n")`.

Comment: @mudasobwa: Very interesting bug in your answer. I didn't understand that it would depend on the gsub history.

Comment: @EricDuminil it happens because `$1` contains _the last match_, and `a = b` is evaluated RTL.

Comment: @mudasobwa: It's not just `a = b`. `s = "123"; s[p "2"] = p "1"` outputs `"2"` then `"1"`

Comment: @EricDuminil well, it is. `""[p 2] = p 1` prints `2 1` because those are two parameters, passing to `String#[]=(index, value)`. The regular expression is not evaluated on that stage, it’s just declared. `"#$1"` is the _interpolation_ and it’s indeed expanded inplace.

Comment: @mudasobwa: That makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you assuming that use of a `MatchData` object is the only alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use backslash without the block:

```
@text.gsub /(-\n)(\S+)\s/, "\\2\n"
```

Also, it's a bit cleaner to use only one group, since the first one above isn't needed:

```
@text.gsub /-\n(\S+)\s/, "\\1\n"
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use [`Regexp.last_match`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Regexp.html#method-c-last_match) :

```
@text.gsub(/(-\n)(\S+)\s/) { Regexp.last_match[2] + "\n" }
```

or :

```
@text.gsub(/-\n(\S+)\s/) { Regexp.last_match[1] + "\n" }
```

Note that the block in `gsub` should be used when logic is involved. Without logic, a second parameter set to `"\\1\n"` or `'\1' + "\n"` would do just fine.

Comment: This solution will also work when using regular expressions in case statements

Answer (score 0):

This solution accounts for errant spaces before newlines and split words that end a sentence or the string. It uses [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html) with a block and no capture groups.

**Code**

```
R = /
    [[:alpha:]]\- # match a letter followed by a hyphen
    \s*\n         # match a newline possibly preceded by whitespace
    [[:alpha:]]+  # match one or more letters
    [.?!]?        # possibly match a sentence terminator
    \n?           # possibly match a newline 
    \s*           # match zero or more whitespaces
    /x            # free-spacing regex definition mode

def remove_hyphens(str)
  str.gsub(R) { |s| s.gsub(/[\n\s-]/, '') << "\n" }
end
```

**Examples**

```
str =<<_       
The wolverine is now es-
sentially absent from
the south-
ern end of its
European range.
_

puts remove_hyphens(str)
The wolverine is now essentially
absent from
the southern
end of its
European range.

puts remove_hyphens("now es-  \nsentially\nabsent")
now essentially
absent

puts remove_hyphens("now es-\nsentially.\nabsent")
now essentially.
absent

remove_hyphens("now es-\nsentially?\n")
  #=> "now essentially?\n" (no extra \n at end)
```